# Public Listview c#

Tags: listview, public

- i have form1 with a listview
- and i have form2 with button who i can set value in my sqlite data base.

all is good but i cant update my listview for see the value because i haven't acces to this control, what ill do

this is my code:
                listViewpays.Items.Clear();

```
            sql = "SELECT * FROM myvalue";
            command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connectdb);
            SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                varlistview1 = new ListViewItem(reader["myvalue"].ToString());
                listView.Items.Add(varlistview1);
                listView.Refresh();

            }
```

this code not work in my form2 :( because i can't acces to listview1(from1)

what i need do please help me

Comment: As raw solution you may make it public in Form2. Better: you expose it through a property. Better: you expose a public method in Form2 that accepts all needed parameters, it creates a ListViewItem and add it to your private ListView. Better: you create a class with relevant properties and you expose a collection in your Form2 and you keep it in sync with your ListView (kind of _poor_ view model, you may even use data binding).

Comment: i have something like this
http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=290128Sanstitre1.jpg

how i can update my listview, my form2 class dont give me acces to listview :/

Comment: For easiest solution (make it public) check Modifiers property (in Design property group) inside WinForms designer. Set listView's Modifiers pseudo-property to "Internal" and it'll be visibile (of course assuming Form2's instance is accessible!)